# How to print tomorrow's date in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, date

I often have to display the date in ConTeXt, but not for today, as displayed with `\date`, but for the next day. How to print tomorrow's date instead?

E.g. August 7, 2019

Comment: `\ctxlua{os.sleep(24*60*60)}\currentdate`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it in Lua.  The function [`os.time()`](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#pdf-os.time) gives you the current time as a POSIX timestamp, i.e. the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.  Add the number of seconds in a day to that to get the same time but tomorrow.  Feed that result into [`os.date`](https://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#pdf-os.date).  Normally `os.date` formats a date to a string, but if the format argument is `"*t"`, it returns a table with the time stamp separated into sensible units.  From that you can extract the day, month, and year and plug it into ConTeXt's `date` function.

Strictly speaking this only works on a POSIX system, but I don't know any system that does *not* use POSIX timestamps.  This approach should also work for at month and year boundaries and even with leap years.  The only problem are [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), because if you execute this exactly at a leap second, you might end up at the same day instead of tomorrow, but these only occur every few years.

```
\starttext

\currentdate

\ctxlua{
    local t = os.date("*t", os.time() + 24*60*60)
    context.date{d = t.day, m = t.month, y = t.year}
}

\stoptext
```

[image]